# Akeneo error after installation / Cache Error

Tags: doctrine, akeneo

My akeneo installation works very fine and without any error. But when I want to start the application, the following error occurs:

> Warning:
>   require(web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PimBundleCatalogBundleEntityLocale.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209
>        Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PimBundleCatalogBundleEntityLocale.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php
>   on line 209
>        Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Compile Error:
>   require(): Failed opening required
>   'web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/var/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PimBundleCatalogBundleEntityLocale.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} Next RuntimeException: Failed to start the
>   session because headers have already been sent by
>   "web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php"
>   at line 209. in
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php:141
>   Stack trace: #0
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoun
>   in
>   web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
>   on line 141

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you clean your cache?

With the command 
`bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` (or env=dev)

or the more "hard" way 
`rm -rf var/cache/*`

Comment: The more "hard" way works, thank you! :) the only problem left is, that there is no dist folder in my web dir....